# ExTJS: how to get all components that are clickable and editable(buttons,triggers,textfields and so on)?

Tags: javascript, extjs

My greetings for everyone!

Currently I need to make my ExtJS app so that it is managed by keyboard . Probably I made it, but the result is not satisfied. So, If you know how to resolve my problem  I will be very glad when you write your solution here.

But now I am trying to make it by another way. My question is:

**ExTJS: how to get all components that are clickable and editable(buttons,triggers,textfields and so on)?**

with respect,
A.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `view.query('.field, .button')` to get buttons and fields on your view

Comment: Query by class name (with dots) is for elements; for component queries, it would be `view.query('button, [isFormField]')`.